# packstack installer CentOS 7 repository issue

Tags: centos7, openstack, yum

I am trying to install packstack installer on my virtualbox running CentOS 7. I have come across two issues:

1) when trying to install I get an error "cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: centos-ceph-nautilus/7/x86_64". I am able to ping my DNS server and also google.com so therefore, external internet connection shouldn't be a problem.

2) When trying to query cat resolv.conf there is nothing - Not sure if I need to add DNS?

Things I have tried:

1) Uncomment baseurl from this directory /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo - Nothing happens
2) Adding another DNS server in cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3 - Nothing happens

Please help me!

Comment: For step 1, did you also enable the repo when you uncommented the baseurl line? There is another line in there which is for 'enabled=1' i.e. it's turned on.

Comment: Hi Michael, what do you mean? This has been driving me nuts over the past 5 days :(

Comment: Can you show an example of what you mean?

Comment: What do you see when you run the command: 'yum repolist all' ?

Comment: When you run the command 'nano /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo' you should see a line near/beneath the 'baseurl=...' part which should be as follows 'enabled=1' (without quotes and again uncommented, so no #). Also, double check your internet connectivity, Ping a few different websites as I've had this issue previously and it was the VMs connectivity to the internet that was the root cause.

Comment: when I run 'nano /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo' I get command not found.

Comment: Use whatever text editor you have installed, likely Vi

Comment: I used Vi. In the base section I do not have enabled=1? Not sure whether I add that section it will make a difference but might try. I can also ping many things. Defs not my internet have a feeling might be the software not sure.